# Ngrx, Rxjs - Merging observable streams returning a new stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to join two observable streams to create a new one I can subscribe too. Both of the input streams return arrays of objects. I tried using the forkJoin operator followed by a pipe map and subscribe like so:

```
forkJoin(
  this.firstObservable$,
  this.secondObservable$
).pipe(
  map(([first, second]) => {
    // here create a new array array = [] and push new Object { first.something, second.something
    // return newArray
  }
  })
).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.data = data;
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work as expected. I also tried this with tap. What would be the proper way?

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the expected behavior? What currently happens? Also, `(data: any) =>` is painfully wrong. If you remove the horrible practice of annotating callback parameter types, TypeScript will do 100x more. Seriously, people, stop writing code like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rxjs provides several operators for combining streams (you can find list of this operators [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/)), in your case I can recommend you use `combineLatest` or `forkJoin`, which to use depend on type of input observables

[forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) - When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

[combileLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) - When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each

notice: ngrx selectors not completes, if your input observables it's ngrx selectors, use `combineLatest`

Comment: Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

ForkJoin itself return an observable which you can subscribe to as

```
forkJoin([
  this.firstObservable$,
  this.secondObservable$
]).subscribe(res => {
    //res[0] is the result emitted for the first observable
});
```

and you need not use `map` to try to merge them

Comment: I've tried subscribing to it directly and then handle the output but the console.log placed inside of the subscribe method never fire.

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas can't comment without seeing your full code but you should see https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61 for a neat and clean demo

Comment: `forkJoin` emit values only after all input observables have been completed, does` this.firstObservable$ `and` this.secondObservable$ `complete?

Comment: try to use `combineLatest` instead (if your input observables not completes)

Comment: @izmaylovdev I chain observables, in the component constructor I invoke the tap method on the observables but they are not subscribed too. I just pass them to the forkJoin which is in the onInit section of the component.

Comment: @izmaylovdev I tried changing forkJoin to combineLatest and it worked. Seems like  forkJoin expects both of the observables to be resolved and combineLatest is fine with just one stream working. One of the streams was not returning data so forkJoin didn't even fire. If you write it into an answer, I will accept it. Thanks,